# Muted Iframe video with googles new Autoplay Policy Changes

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, vimeo, autoplay

googles just updated there "[Autoplay Policy Changes](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes)" but I want to implement a muted auto-playing Vimeo background video and after reading the article I believed adding the following to the iframe would work.

chrome version: 68

```
allow="autoplay; fullscreen"
```

but no luck and I'm not sure what else to try other then the JS API which i don't even know if it will make a difference.

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/265188275?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=false&byline=false&title=false&byline=false&frameborder=0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen">
```

thanks in advance for any helpful advice.

Comment: What article are you referencing? What version of Chrome are you using? I cannot reproduce the behavior you describe with your embed code -- it autoplays as expected.

Comment: my apologies I have updated the post with that information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Vimeo embedded iframe player as a background video, you should use the embed code with the background parameter instead of the autoplay and loop parameters:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?background=1" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The background parameter will hide all player buttons and elements (play/pause, playbar, title, byline, etc.), loop the video, autoplay the video, and mute the video. That last part is important - by default, Chrome will always allow muted videos to autoplay. For videos to autoplay with audio turned on, Chrome uses a "Media Engagement Index" to determine if the viewer actually wants or expects video with audio to autoplay when navigating to your page. That whole process is documented by Google here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

The background parameter of the Vimeo Player is documented here: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115011183028-Embedding-background-videos